# writing to a file in python and getting permissions deny

Tags: python, permissions, traceback

Alright I have a method:

```
def manage_file(current_city):
    read_f = open('temp.txt', 'rb')
    dict = pickle.load(read_f)
    read_f.close()

    dict[time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S ') + current_city] = current_temp
    write_f = open('temp.txt', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(dict, write_f)
    return dict
```

For some reason I am getting an error :

> line 21, in manage_file write_f = open('temp.txt', 'wb') IOError:
>   [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'temp.txt'

Anyone familiar with this, and know a solution?

Comment: It looks like you do not have permission to write to that file.

Comment: Do you know of a way to give myself permissions? I am running ubuntu on a virtualbox.

Comment: what does `touch foo` in the same directory tell you?

Comment: When I put in the command 'touch foo' it created an empty text file named 'foo' in the same directory im in.

Comment: Try changing the name. I'm not familiar with ubuntu, but maybe it's a reserved name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jan Vlcinsky comments, you don't seem to have write permissions to that file.  If you have sufficient permissions to change file permissions (may require that you know the super user password), you can change file permissions with `chmod` in a terminal on a linux machine or on a mac.

You would:

- open a terminal
- `cd` to the correct directory
- type in `chmod abc temp.txt`

a, b, c should be numbers representable in binary between 000 and 111 (so numbers between 0 and 7).  Each digit of the binary representation encodes read, write, and execute privileges respectively.  a is for the file owner's permissions, b is for the file's group permissions, and c is for everyone else's permissions.

So you could do `chmod 755 temp.txt` to give the file owner permission to read, write and execute (7 = 111) and give everyone else read and execute (5 = 101) permissions.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on what the numbers meant I never have known. I had to use 'sudo chmod 777 temp.txt' for some reason 755 still wouldn't change it over from being a 'locked' file.

Comment: Perhaps you are not the file owner?  If someone else created the file, then you'd need chmod xx7 temp.txt for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from a shell prompt (often $) in the directory containing temp.txt:

```
chmod 755 .
chmod 755 temp.txt
```